# Adding a TLS/SSL layer to communications..?

Tags: c, ssl

My stuff is made with several components among which some are written in C. As I would like to add some security features, I am thinking of communicating over an SSL/TLS layer.

Could you advise me some good lib to do this (if possible) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [axTLS](http://axtls.cerocclub.com.au/) which works great on both our server (.NET) and our embedded systems (Linux and uClinux). We had problems getting OpenSSL to work well on uClinux.
axTLS is not as feature complete as OpenSSL yet so make sure it meets your requirements before using it.

Answer (score 4):

[GnuTLS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) (Please note that it is mainly LGPL not GPL so you **can** link to it). At least I prefere it's API over [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Also there is Mozilla's [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/intro.html).

Comment: Yes, GnuTLS is, IMHO, simpler for the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

How about [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)?

Comment: Warning, the licence, while free, is compatible with the GPL, which may be a problem for some applications.

Comment: To be clear, though, it's not GPL. It uses the Apache license, which is significantly different and does not require publication of changes.

Comment: @bortzmeyer: You mean incompatible. Yes - I know that that was a spelling mistake but just to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not spending your time trying to implement an SSL function in your app. Instead, you could just use an existing SSL-tunnel software, which creates an SSL tunnel in front of your existing socket application.

```
Internet --- [SSLTunnel] --- Your App
```

For example, you could tell the SSL tunnel to listen on port 443 (https) and forward all decrypted packets to port 80 (http). For your custom application, it will just see decrypted packets.

There are plenty of free apps that do it. Just google for one.

Comment: if by implementation in application you mean using the library what is the benefit of using SSL-tunnel software? It seems to me that you add the complexity and overhead as you need to do IPC etc. You cannot force SSL (for example you cannot force SSL on login page) or implement STARTTLS.

Comment: This is philosophical. Depends on what you subscribe to. I try to reduce the amount of code that needs to be written/maintained. If it is not needed, then why bother. I'd even do away with writing simple socket apps and just use something like inetd instead.

Comment: I'd say that the amount of code have negligible difference (a few lines usually. Even less if you use highier level library).

Comment: If you need more complexity, things will get more complex e.g. if you need to perform client verification, you need more lines etc. It may only be a negligible effort to code but not a negligible effort to test. You need to check the code against all possible security attacks. That's non-trivial. Even if the ssl library is 'good', the app's implementation of it may be flawed.

Comment: But then you do need to put is somewhere. If you need the client verification by certificate than again - you need IPC which is arguably not much simpler then using a library. Yes - security is hard and yes, dividing code into autonomous pieces usually helps but I fail to see how is it much simpler then using library.

Comment: I think that you already see it. Like I said, it's philosophical and depends on your vantage point. A programmer will likely choose the solution that involves code. A sysadmin may choose the solution with less maintenance. A security person may choose one with less human involvement. A proj manager may choose one with less time. etc.

Answer (score 0):

CyaSSL would be an excellent choice to consider.  This is an embedded SSL library written in C which has been optimized for speed and size.  It can be up to 20 times smaller than OpenSSL, and can be quite a bit faster as well.

Among the feature list are a minimum size of 30-100kb and an OpenSSL compatibility layer.  The full feature list can be found on the yaSSL website here:

http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/Products_cyassl.html.

It is dual licensed under the open source GPLv2 as well as a commercial license (for support).  It is updated very frequently with new features.  I think one of the cool features is support for the RABBIT and HC-128 stream ciphers from the eStream project.